# TypeError: Object # has no method 'forEach' at new LoadersList while setting up react project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I was successful setting up te react development set up. But running npm start is giving following error.

I cant figure out from where this error is getting generated.  Pls help!

```
    TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'forEach'  at new LoadersList 
    (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\webpack-
    core\lib\LoadersList.js:7:12) at new NormalModuleFactory (C:\Users
    \User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack
    \lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:16:17) at Compiler.createNormalModuleFactory 
    (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack    
    \lib\Compiler.js:369:28)  at Compiler.newCompilationParams (C:\Users    
    \User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:382:29) at 
    Compiler.compile (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack
    \lib\Compiler.js:389:20)    at Watching.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\AppData
    \Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:46:17)    at Compiler.next 
    (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable
    \lib\Tapable.js:67:11)   at Compiler.invalidAsyncPlugin (C:\Users\User\AppData
    \Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\webpack-
    dev-middleware\middleware.js:80:3) at Compiler.applyPluginsAsync (C:\Users
    \User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable
    \lib\Tapable.js:71:13)  at Watching._go (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming
    \npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:44:16)
```

Please suggest. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Object #<Object> has no method 'forEach'

    forEach will work for Array, means looping the array, 
but in your case your calling the method `forEach` in Object.
```

Correct:

```
[].forEach.
```

what you are doing is:

```
{}.forEach
```

Comment: Hi, actually i havent started writing any code. this seems to be auto generated , so im perplexed where it could be used.

Comment: any suggestions where the root cause could be?

Answer (score 0):

if anyone faces the same issue, The reason is because the loaders in webpack.config.js was a object  instead of array of object values.

ie. all loaders must be wrapped in an array. as array of objects.

`module:{
    loaders:**[**
        {
            test:/\.jsx?$/,
            exclude:/node_modules/,
            loader:'babel',
            query:{
                presets:['react','es2015']
            }
        }
    **]**`
}